# How to select the item with highest value in a list

Tags: netlogo

I have a list for each turtle I am considering in my model. I would like to select an item of a list, specifically, the item with highest quality. Quality is a parameter in the range [0,1]. 
My issues regards how to assign the parameter to each item, then select the item with the highest parameter value.

*To better explain*: an example of list is `(item 4, item3, item2, item1)`. What I would like is: item 4 with quality #, item 3 with quality #, and so on.
When I create the items of a list, they have a quality parameter (it's turtle-own): `(quality random-float 1)`.
Then, I should have something like this:
`item4 0.2, item3 1, item2 0.2, item1 0.5`.
What I would like to select is the item with highest quality, i.e. `item3` with quality equal to `1`.

To assign the parameter, I considered:

```
ask one-of turtles
     [
      ifelse empty? mylist
        [
          set quality random-float 1
          ...
        ]
     ]
```

I do not know if this is the right way to assign an attribute to an item of a list in Netlogo.

The steps for selecting an item are:

1. Select a turtle
2. Check that its list is not empty
3. Select the item with highest quality of its list

Based on them, I would write as follows:

```
let mylist [ item4 item3 item2 item1 item0 item6] 
let max-value max mylist 
let max-index position max mylist
```

The problem is that I am not sure that I am selecting the item with the highest quality, because I am not completely sure  am assigning correctly the quality to an item.

I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Sort the items in asc. order of their values and then pick the first element from your sorted list.

Comment: Thanks Omarito. However, the list should be ordered from the most recent to the oldest item. However, the list looks like [item4 item3...], not with the values of the quality

Comment: If you don't want to sort the list of items then declare variable that is called index_max and set it to 0 (point to the first element) then loop through your list starting from 1 (second element) till the last element comparing item[i].value to item[index_max] and if its bigger then update index_max to point to i.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. How can I check in the observer, which quality value is assigned to a list? Right now, my list looks like: `[5 7 17 23 ...]`, where `5 7 17` are the items added, not the quality assigned

Comment: You can define a structure, lets call it Item, that pack the item proprieties together (itemID, itemName, ..., itemValue) and then you can have everything in one place to make it easier for you to acces itemValue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have a structure that packs all the item proprieties together (ItemID, ItemName, ..., ItemValue) and an array of Items.

```
Item(ItemID, ItemName, ..., ItemValue) // these are the proprieties of our object Item
Item arr_items[NB_ITEMS] //  the array (list) of items you have
```

You can use the following algorithm, written in pseudo code, and transfer it to the language you use to pick the item with the highest value.

**Pseudo code:**

```
// Lets assume your array of items is called "arr_items"
// Lets also assume indexing start from 0
index_max  = 0 // first index
for i = 0 to length(arr_items) - 1: // loop though all items
    // if the current ith item have ItemValue bigger than index_max's items ItemValue 
    if arr_items[item_max].ItemValue > arr_items[i].ItemValue then 
        index_max = i // then change index_max to be i
return index_max  // return the index of the item with the highest value
```