# Adding attributes to items of a list

Tags: netlogo

I would like to know how to add attributes for each element of a list. 
In particular, I have a list made by adding items at each tick. Each item has two attributes. These attributes are important to me, as I want to select an item based on the value of its attribute. 
I did something like this:

```
ask one-of turtles ;; turtles have cars
[ set attribute_1 ;; cars' attribute
  set attribute_2 ;; cars' attribute

  set mylist fput car mylist
]
```

I would like something like this `[car1 attribute_1 attribute_2, car2 attribute_1 attribute_2, car3...]`.
At the moment I have `[car1 car2 car3...]`.
Once associated the attributes to the items, I would need to pick the item with highest value from the list. The user Omarito provided me a possible solution: [How to select the item with highest value in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58582931/how-to-select-the-item-with-highest-value-in-a-list?noredirect=1#comment103480499_58582931), but it is not completely clear to me how to pick an item up.

What I would like to ask you is if it is possible to have something like `[car1 attribute_1 attribute_2, car2 attribute_1 attribute_2, car3...]` or if I can only have something like

```
[car1 car2 car3...]
```

or
`[[attribute_1 attribute_2] [attribute_1 attribute_2] ...]`. 
If I write  `set mylist fput [(list attribute_1 attribute_2)]`, I receive the error message: expected a literal value.

I hope you can help me. Thanks

UPDATE: After Nicolas' answer, I edited the code as follows:

```
 ask one-of turtles
     [
        hatch-cars 1[ ;; buy a new car 
        set attribute_1 random-float 1
        set attribute_2 random-float 1
        ]
        let this-car self
        set my-list fput this-car my-list

 ; ask turtles [show my-list]
        set new_car? true
        set old_car? false

        set new_car new_car + 1 ;; how could I update it after the change?
  ]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Keep in mind that `turtles` refers to *all* breeds of turtles, so if you create a `cars` breed, `turtles` will include `cars`. You should create a separate breed for your other agents (you can name it `agents`, `buyers`, `people` or whatever) and then use that breed instead of, e.g., `ask one-of turtles` where you need­ it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this problem, but I will just give you two.

Let's start with the one closest to the way you're currently trying to do things.

```
turtles-own [ my-list ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 3 [
    set my-list [] ; start with empty list
    foreach range 5 [ car -> ; let's pretend cars are just numbers
      let attribute-1 precision (random-float 1) 2
      let attribute-2 precision (random-float 1) 2
      set my-list fput (list car attribute-1 attribute-2) my-list
    ]
  ]
  ask turtles [
    show my-list
    print "  Best car by attribute 1:"
    let best-by-1 last sort-by [ [a b] -> item 1 a < item 1 b ] my-list
    print word "    Sublist:    " best-by-1
    print word "    Car number: " item 0 best-by-1
    print "  Best car by attribute 2:"
    let best-by-2 last sort-by [ [a b] -> item 2 a < item 2 b ] my-list
    print word "    Sublist:    " best-by-2
    print word "    Car number: " item 0 best-by-2
    print "--------"
  ]
end
```

Most of this code is for creating the turtles and displaying the result, but the two key lines are:

```
set my-list fput (list car attribute-1 attribute-2) my-list
```

for adding sublists to the main list, and:

```
let best-by-1 last sort-by [ [a b] -> item 1 a < item 1 b ] my-list
```

for sorting the main list by a specific attribute taken from the sublist. You can then use `item 0 best-by-1` to get the car itself.

That being said, if you want to use NetLogo to its full potential, you should probably create a car breed:

```
breed [ cars car ]
cars-own [
  attribute-1
  attribute-2
]

breed [ agents an-agent ]
agents-own [ my-list ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-agents 3 [
    set my-list [] ; start with empty list
    hatch-cars 5 [
      set attribute-1 precision (random-float 1) 2
      set attribute-2 precision (random-float 1) 2
      let this-car self
      ask myself [ set my-list fput this-car my-list ]
    ]
  ]
  ask agents [
    show my-list
    print "  Best car by attribute 1:"
    let best-by-1 max-one-of turtle-set my-list [ attribute-1 ]
    print (word "    " best-by-1 ", attribute-1 = " [ attribute-1 ] of best-by-1)
    print "  Best car by attribute 2:"
    let best-by-2 max-one-of turtle-set my-list [ attribute-2 ]
    print (word "    " best-by-2 ", attribute-1 = " [ attribute-2 ] of best-by-2)
  ]
end
```

The [`max-one-of`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#max-one-of) primitive makes it easy to pick the best car and everything else will also probably be easier if you're working with agents instead of lists.

Comment: Thank you so much Nicolas. Your answer is great and extremely helpful, also for its clearness. I would have wanted to create a new breed only to include the attributes. I would have a more question: if I want to create/assign the car's attributes not when I create the turtles, but when I call one of them (`ask one-of turtles`), how could I change the code properly? Is t by calling `hatch-breeds`? Sorry but this is the part that it is not completely clear to me, also because I have no so much experience in using Netlogo.

Comment: It wouldn't be much different: `ask one-of agents [ hatch-cars 1 [ set attribute-1 random-float 1 let this-car self ask myself [ set my-list fput this-car my-list ] ] ] ]`

Comment: I updated the question after your answer, showing what I edited to ask if it is correct. Thank you for your help Nicolas